# How to track down JavaScript that is modifying the inline style of a div in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm messing with a WordPress plugin. When I scroll down about 50 pixels from the top, something is changing the inline style attribute of a div tag. How can I track down what is making this change? Is there a Chrome feature or dev tool that can point to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [Chrome Dev Tools Timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline) feature. It outputs all of the functions fired by events, the type of event, and the time they were run.

Comment: perfect. I figured it was in there somewhere.